# How can I get the number of the loaded panel in Coda Slider 3?

Tags: jquery, coda-slider

I've implemented the Coda Slider 3.0 ([this one](http://kevinbatdorf.github.com/codaslider/)) and I need to get the URL of the image which is currently displaying. Does anyone know how to do this?

I know there is a setting called "firstPanelToLoad", so I figured there must be some way to get the number of the current panel.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding my own functionality in the javascript. I added another option to $.fn.liquidSlider.options which become my custom callback function:

```
$.fn.liquidSlider.options = {
...
swipe: true,
swipeArgs: undefined,
customCallback: function(currentSlide) {}
};
```

And then in the setNextPanel function you can call your custom callback with the currently selected panel:

```
setNextPanel: function(direction) {
...
    self.options.customCallback(self.nextPanel);
}
```